# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'datasets' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to use `Chart.js` in my program. I have hosted my php and JavaScript files in a public hosting site. When I try to run the chart function, I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'datasets' of undefined". Please find the code below.

```
<head>
    <title>Operation Details</title>
    <script src="../Chart.js"></script>
</head>
```

```
var barChartData = { 
    labels : [month1,month2,month3,month4,month5,month6,month7,month8,month9,month10,month11,month12],
    datasets : [ 
        { 
        label: "My First dataset", fillColor : "rgba(192,192,192,0.5)", strokeColor : "rgba(192,192,192,0.8)", highlightFill: "rgba(192,192,192,0.75)", highlightStroke: "rgba(192,192,192,1)",
        data : [avg1[temp[i]],avg2[temp[i]]]
        }
    ]
}
//...

window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
        responsive: true
    });
//...
}
```

Chart.js:

```
helpers.each(data.datasets,function(dataset,datasetIndex){

    var datasetObject = {
    //...
```

I'm completely new to JavaScript and to this forum. If something is wrong, please advice me on that.

Comment: @blex that is in Chart.js it's different scope

Comment: i think your syntax is wrong, nothing can be said without seeing whole code.

Comment: @Shahzad Thanks for the reply. I'm able to run the same code in xampp and bar chart is getting displayed. But when I try to run through public hosted site, i'm getting error. I'm not sure whether server is not recognizing Chart.js file I have mentioned. Can you please let me know what do you mean by syntax is wrong?

Comment: If it works locally but not online, check that all your files are hosted correctly. Go to your site, open your JS console (hit F12), and see if there are any errors (_Failed to load resource: xyz..._) or if there is any 404 in your "Network" tab (you might need to reload the page once you opened that tab).

Comment: @blex Thanks for the comments. I checked and the webpage showing me the following                                                                         Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'datasets' of undefined Chart.Type.extend.initialize Chart.js:2122                               Chart.Type  Chart.js:833                             Chart.Type.extend.ChartType Chart.js:1056     Chart.Type.extend.Chart.(anonymous function) Chart.js:1084 window.onload  line_new.php:690

Comment: `data` argument is undefined, maybe you should put all code